# send payload in get request in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am making a login form with ember in front end and node in back end. After login node api returns an authentication token which is saved in browser session. I want to send this token in every further request made to the other APIs i.e., sending it as a payload in each get requests from ember. this is how I call the /registers API with which i need to send the token as payload.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
 model() {
     var users = this.store.find('register');
     return users;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send it as a GET parameter, you'll need to customize the serializers for the various models that hit the API.
You can also customize the headers being sent with every store request by customizing the application wide adapter like the following example:

```
// app/adapters/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    headers: function() {
        return {
            'MyCustomHeader': 'something'
        };
    }
});
```

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_headers-customization

Comment: thankx for your solution, I also got a solution https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1576 to add some data as query string in the request, which sounded useful to my purpose.